# HTML: making iframe height fixed

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a we page that is included inside an iframe on another domain. The issue is that the iframe is always loaded with vertical scrollbar. I checked the markup and here is how they include the iFrame:

```
<iframe class="plugin-frame js-plugin-frame" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" width="100%" height="auto" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-top-navigation" src="https://mydomain/mypage.html"></iframe>
```

If I change the above to:

```
<iframe class="plugin-frame js-plugin-frame" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" width="100%" min-height="600px" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-top-navigation" src="https://mydomain/mypage.html"></iframe>
```

it works.

Is there anything that I can do on my page to make it work. I need to get rid of the vertical scrollbar and have no control over the third party markup. Is there anything needed in the markup of my iframe to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you can add some css in your website targeting the iframe height!

Comment: You can't use css with iframe as selector and add the min-height? That should work.

Comment: I can not alter the css of iframe as the containing page and page inside iframe are on different domains.

Comment: Seeing as you have no control over the page which contains the iframe, the above suggestions won't work. You can try `html, body { overflow: hidden; }` in your page's CSS to eliminate any scrollbars on your site's side.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have the scrollbar, but do want to allow scrolling, you can add the following CSS (only works in WebKit):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none}
```

If you don't want to have the scrollbar and you don't want scrolling then you can do this:

```
body, html { overflow-y: hidden }
```

Since I assume you want to only apply these styles if your page is iframed, use this JavaScript to get the job done:

```
if (top != self) {
     var style = document.createElement('style');
     style.type = 'text/css';
     style.innerHTML = '::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none}';
     document.head.appendChild(style);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. While this does remove the scrollbars from the frame, the content is all trimmed. With scrollbard I can see the full page but without its just not possible.

Comment: @user1640256 Here, I changed the JavaScript solution to use my first answer instead of my second. Scrollbars should be hidden, but scrolling should be possible now.